# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to search records using CreateDate as StartdDate and EndDate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Entity Framework to implement an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API.

I have this model class `Booking`:

```
public class Booking : BaseEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string HotelId { get; set; }
    public string BookingReference { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckIn { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckOut { get; set; }
    public int NoOfPeople { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public Hotel Hotel { get; set; }
    public bool PaymentStatus {  get; set; }
    public string RoomId {  get; set; }
    public Room Room {  get; set; }
    public Payment Payment { get; set; }
}
```

Then this give rise to `GetBookingResponseDto`:

```
public class GetBookingResponseDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }
    public string RoomType { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckIn { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckOut { get; set; }
    public string Hotel { get; set; }
    public string BookingReference { get; set; }
    public bool PaymentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

**PagedResult:**

```
public class PageResult<T>
{
    public T PageItems { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }
    public int PreviousPage { get; set; }
}
```

This is the repository:

```
public IQueryable<Booking> GetBookings()
{
    var query = _context.Bookings.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(b => b.Hotel)
            .Include(b => b.Payment)
            .Include(b => b.Room)
            .ThenInclude(r => r.Roomtype)
            .OrderBy(b => b.CreatedDate);
    return query;
}
```

Then finally got everything rapped up in the `BookingService`:

```
public async Task<Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<GetBookingResponseDto>>>> GetCustomerBookings(PagingDto paging)
{
    var bookings = _unitOfWork.Booking.GetBookings();
    var pageResult = await bookings.PaginationAsync<Booking, GetBookingResponseDto>(paging.PageSize, paging.PageNumber, _mapper);

    Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<GetBookingResponseDto>>> response = new()
        {
            Data = pageResult,
            Message = "Bookings Fetched",
            StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK,
            Succeeded = true
        };

    return response;
}
```

I want to filter/search the booking record between dates (`StartDate` and `EndDate`) using the `CreatedDate`. But by default, the whole records for bookings should be displayed when no `StardDate` and `EndDate` are selected.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: the question is not very clear. what means that note? Could you show some examples of your data? In any case the model is Datetime, not Datetime? so there is no option to "starddate" and "enddate" are no selected.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli - What I mean is the I want to filter/search records between dates  (StartDate and EndDate) using CreatedDate. That means CreatedDate should be used as StartDate and EndDate

Comment: and where is StartDate and EndDate in your model?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli - As I stated earlier, CreatedDate is StartDate and EndDate.   It is to filter between those two dates

Comment: Yes but there is no specification about StartDate/EndDate in your models, parameters neither repository

Comment: @LeandroBardelli - That's why I'm asking the question

Comment: This seems to be a functional question not applicable to S.O. I would assume you have a database where do you save your data? Could you show your repository queryng the database?

Comment: I just do something like this: .Where(m => m.CreatedDate.Date >= CurrentFromDate.Date && m.CreatedDate.Date <= CurrentToDate.Date)  By default CurrentToDate = DateTime.Today... and CurrentFromDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-12)  (that's for a year but you could use .min or -lots...)